# Can't change UINavigationBar prompt color

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am unable to change the prompt color on my navigation bar. I've tried the code below in `viewDidLoad`, but nothing happens.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

[image: navigation bar image]

Am I missing something? Is the code above wrong?

Comment: try  `navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]`

Comment: In swift 4 `titleTextAttributes` is of type `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]?`. `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is a string, so that way will not build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you're right about this one. You need to use `UIAppearance` to style the prompt text on iOS 11.

I've filed radar #34758558 that the `titleTextAttributes` property just stopped working for prompt in iOS 11.

The good news is that there are a couple of workarounds, which we can uncover by using Xcode's view hierarchy debugger:

[image: Screenshot of UINavigation Bar Prompt on iOS 11]

```
// 1. This works, but potentially changes *all* labels in the navigation bar. 
// If you want this, it works.
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.white
```

The prompt is just a UILabel. If we use UIAppearance's `whenContainedInInstancesOf:`, we can pretty easily update the color the way we want.

If you look closely, you'll notice that there's also a wrapper view on the UILabel. It has its own class that might respond to UIAppearance...

[image: Screenshot of private UINavigationBar subview]

```
// 2. This is a more precise workaround but it requires using a private class.

if let promptClass = NSClassFromString("_UINavigationBarModernPromptView") as? UIAppearanceContainer.Type
{
  UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [promptClass]).textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

I'd advise sticking to the more general solution, since it doesn't use private API. (App review, etc.) Check out what you get with either of these two solutions:

[image: Properly colored prompt text]

Comment: @fivewood Which part doesn't work? Part 1 or part 2?

Comment: The conditional is true and the body of the if statement seems to execute, but there is no change to my prompt text.

Comment: Which version of iOS? This answer is for iOS 11. I'm curious if the private API (SPI) or internal class name changed in iOS 12. That's the first place I'd look here.

Comment: iOS 12.1.1 beta 3

Comment: Have in mind that this will also change the color of the hint of searchbar's textfield. If so you solution 2

Answer (score 25):

I was able to make the prompt color white on iOS 11 was setting the barStyle to black. I set the other color attributes (like the desired background color) using the appearance proxy:

```
myNavbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; // Objective-C
myNavbar.barStyle = .black // Swift
```

Comment: It might be worth stating explicitly that setting the bar style to .black does *not* mean your navigation bar color will be black. It will be whatever color you set it to when you use the appearance proxy as Markus mentioned. The .black setting is the **style** of the nav bar

Comment: Works great, this should be the accepted answer - it's simple, and doesn't have side effects or use private methods.

Comment: Setting the `barstyle` to `.black` affects an embedded search bar as well. So the search bar gets a black background. Almost certainly not what you want when you're using `UISearchController`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
for view in self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
    let subviews = view.subviews
    if subviews.count > 0, let label = subviews[0] as? UILabel {
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

It will be a temporary workaround until they'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

More complicated version to support old and new iOS

```
    func updatePromptUI(for state: State) {
    if (state != .Online) {
        //workaround for SOFT-7019 (iOS 11 bug - Offline message has transparent background)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            showPromptView()
        } else {
            showOldPromptView()
        }
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.prompt = nil
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.removePromptView()
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = nil
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.lightGray]
        }
    }
}

private func showOldPromptView() {
    self.navigationItem.prompt = "Network Offline. Some actions may be unavailable."
    let navbarFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: navbarFont, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
}

private func showPromptView() {
    self.navigationItem.prompt = String()
    self.removePromptView()

    let promptView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 18))
    promptView.backgroundColor = .red
    let promptLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: promptView.frame.width, height: 14))
    promptLabel.text = "Network Offline. Some actions may be unavailable."
    promptLabel.textColor = .white
    promptLabel.textAlignment = .center
    promptLabel.font = promptLabel.font.withSize(13)
    promptView.addSubview(promptLabel)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(promptView)
}

private func removePromptView() {
    for view in self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a custom `UINavigationBar` subclass and overriding `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.topItem.prompt) {
        UILabel *promptLabel = [[self recursiveSubviewsOfKind:UILabel.class] selectFirstObjectUsingBlock:^BOOL(UILabel *label) {
            return [label.text isEqualToString:self.topItem.prompt];
        }];
        promptLabel.textColor = self.tintColor;
    }
}
```

Basically I'm enumerating all UILabels in the subview hierarchy and check if their text matches the prompt text. Then we set the textColor to the tintColor (feel free to use a custom color). That way, we don't have to hardcode the private `_UINavigationBarModernPromptView` class as the prompt label's superview. So the code is be a bit more future-proof.

Converting the code to Swift and implementing the helper methods `recursiveSubviewsOfKind:` and `selectFirstObjectUsingBlock:` are left as an exercise to the reader .

Comment: Finally a real answer to the problem! 10x

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updatePrompt()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updatePrompt()
    }
    func updatePrompt() {
        navigationItem.prompt = " "
        for view in navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] where NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "_UINavigationBarModernPromptView" {
            if let prompt = view.subviews.first as? UILabel {
                prompt.text = "Hello Red Prompt"
                prompt.textColor = .red
            }
        }
        navigationItem.title = "This is the title (Another color)"
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could check for label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth instead of _UINavigationBarModernPromptView . This label is the only auto-shrinking in the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Moshe's first answer didn't work for me because it changed the labels inside of system VCs like mail and text compose VCs. I could change the background of those nav bars but that opens up a whole other can of worms. I didn't want to go the private class route so I only changed UILabels contained inside of my custom navigation bar subclass.

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [NavigationBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:->

```
navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red]
```

Comment: In Swift 4 `titleTextAttributes` is of type `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]?`. `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue` is a `String`. Your code will not compile in Swift 4.

Comment: navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
Edit

If you need to change the text attributes of the large title you need to use the new largeTitleTextAttributes property on UINavigationBar:





UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on iOS11 (xCode 9.0.0). The large title change color but not the prompt!

Answer (score -1):

I've found next work around for iOS 11. 
You need set at `viewDidLoad`
`navigationItem.prompt = UINavigationController.fakeUniqueText`
and after that put next thing

```html
    navigationController?.promptLabel(completion: { label in
    label?.textColor = .white
    label?.font = Font.regularFont(size: .p12)
        })

    extension UINavigationController {
    public static let fakeUniqueText = "\n\n\n\n\n"
    func promptLabel(completion: @escaping (UILabel?) -> Void) {
        gloabalThread(after: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            guard let `self` = self else {
                return
            }
            let label = self.findPromptLabel(at: self.navigationBar)
            mainThread {
                completion(label)
            }
        }
    }

    func findPromptLabel(at view: UIView) -> UILabel? {
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            if label.text == UINavigationController.fakeUniqueText {
                return label
            }
        }
        var label: UILabel?
        view.subviews.forEach { subview in
            if let promptLabel = findPromptLabel(at: subview) {
                label = promptLabel
            }
        }
        return label
    }
    }


    public func mainThread(_ completion: @escaping SimpleCompletion) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: completion)
    }


    public func gloabalThread(after: Double, completion: @escaping SimpleCompletion) {
       DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + after) {
       completion()
    }
}
```