# Can't change UINavigationBar prompt color and font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I can change title appearance and its work very well but I can't change prompt font and color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change UINavigationBar prompt color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266310/cant-change-uinavigationbar-prompt-color)

Comment: that answer is not correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code in `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`:

```swift
for view in self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
    let subviews = view.subviews
    if subviews.count > 0, let label = subviews[0] as? UILabel {
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use it in `viewDidAppear` it's worked from me

Comment: and make sure the navigation bar have `_UINavigationBarModernPromptView`